# Zip each Excel file in a folder separately.

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently stuck trying to zip every file in a folder ***separately***. I do not want to zip the folder or zip all the files together. They need to be zipped separately in order for me to traverse the XML folder later and extract images which are going to be OCR'd. My attempt was to use VBA and just change the file extensions

```
Sub Create_Zip()

 Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
 Dim objFile As File
 Dim myFolder
 Dim strFilename As String
 Const zipDir As String = "\\...\Zip Test"

 Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
 Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(zipDir)

 For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
     strFilename = objFile.Name
     new_strFilename = Replace(strFilename, ".xlsx", ".zip")
 Next objFile
End Sub
```

According to the "immediate window" the string variable "***new_strFilename***" has the file extension "***.zip"*** but I am not seeing the change in the folder.

Comment: Why not use any Zip program out there, that has this functionality, built-in?

Comment: ^ did not know they existed - I have never really worked with zipped files before ?

Comment: [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) is freeware, it can zip all files in a folder, to separate archives.

Comment: Apart from that you assign the desired value to new_strFilename (which you have not dimensioned by the way) but you do not assign it to the actual file (something like objFile.Name = new_StrFilename)

Comment: @Anuga I downloaded and it zipped all the files together not individually but I might be using it wrong.

Comment: @JanB Thanks (you should answerize that) . I do encounter an error now though ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the new filename to the variable `new_strFilename` but not to the actual file.

Since you are getting an error when trying `objFile.Name = new_strFilename` I assume that property is read-only.

In general if you want to rename a file use the Name function:

```
Name oldFile As newFile
```

where oldFile and newFile are strings containing the whole path to a file.

In your example something like this:

```
 For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
     strFilename = objFile.Name
     new_strFilename = Replace(strFilename, ".xlsx", ".zip")

     Name zipDir & "\" & strFilename As zipDir & "\" & new_strFilename
 Next objFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  to use **name  A as B** .

```
Sub Create_Zip()

 Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
 Dim objFile As File
 Dim myFolder
 Dim strFilename As String
 Const zipDir As String = "\\...\Zip Test"

 Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
 Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(zipDir)

 For Each objFile In myFolder.Files
     strFilename = objFile.name
     new_strFilename = Replace(strFilename, ".xlsx", ".zip")
     Name zipDir & "\" & strFilename As zipDir & "\" & new_strFilename
 Next objFile
End Sub
```